# url_for Is Not Understanding My Variables

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

Here, I'm trying to make it so that, whenever a user uploads an image, it will be displayed to all users. "Data" contains the file name i.e. "files/dog.png". For some reason, newImg.src only becomes "/static/". My code is shown below:

```
var chatDiv = document.getElementById('messages');
const newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = "{{url_for('static', filename = data )}}"
chatDiv.appendChild(newImg)
```

I have already tried to use Jinja2 string interpolation like this:

```
newImg.src = "{{url_for('static', filename = {{ data }} )}}"
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

And yes, even after removing the brackets, my code still doesn't work(pls reopen this post).

Assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to find a work around! You have to use .replace to replace the string with another variable.

```
newImg.src = "{{url_for('static', filename = 'data')}}".replace('data', data)
```